# Chromium loses cookies upon reboot? 16.04

Tags: chromium

When I reboot my computer, Chromium seems to lose its cookies, as I need to log in on all sites again.

I need to type in all the logins manually, but if I give it a few minutes, it suggests my logins and passwords.

It used to work in the way that I was logged in everywhere at launch. I am not aware of any changes I'd have done.

When I close Chromium and launch it again, it works as I'd like to. Logins are lost only upon computer reboot.

Can I somehow make it remember me again? Thanks.

Comment: Did you check your settings? Theres an option that you may have selected to clear all cookies when you close the browser.

Comment: Yes, I have that one unchecked. When I close the browser and reopen, it works good, the cookies seem to be cleared upon computer reboot.